# Excel VBA Delete Array Column in Double Loop to Increase Performance

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I am looking to speed up my code. My code consists of a double loop, intially Looping through the headers of a master table followed by looping (nested) through a source array to paste the source data whenever the master and source headers match (the source array column order varies from time to time) . ATM my code imports 1000 rows of data each in 113 columns in 8 seconds.

My idea for optimizing the code futher is to delete the matching array column in the nested loop after the values are coppied over, thereby reducing the amount of array headers to search through for each succesfull loop interation. Is this possible? will it make my code run faster?

I seached the forum and considered redim'ing my array, but my array range is declared as...

```
SourceWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange
```

...and i wonder how i can exclude the array header each time the loop succesfully matches the headers.

```
   'Loop through master table headers
    For x = 1 To MasterTable.HeaderRowRange.Count

        'Loop through array headers and copy values to master
        For i = LBound(ArrImport, 2) To UBound(ArrImport, 2)

            If MasterTable.Range(1, x).Value = ArrImport(1, i) Then
                MainWB.Sheets("Brdx").Range(Cells(h, x).Address, Cells(h + SourceTable.ListRows.Count - 1, x).Address).Value = _
                SourceWB.Sheets(1).Range(SourceTable.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.Address).Value


                Exit For
            End If

        Next i
    Next x
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can put the whole lot into arrays so only touching the sheets at start and end? That would be a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. So you suggest that i load the master table into an array aswell, and then continue with the 'merge' operation?

Comment: Yes that was roughly my thinking. You want to touch the worksheets as little as possible as that is expensive i/o.

Comment: Also, once you have completed your array manipulation, when you come to write back to the sheet, use `Transpose`.. a lot quicker than just trying to write to a range

Comment: Also, if you have working code, which you are looking to optimize, Code Review might be the stack of your choice.